# How to iterate over column values for each group and track sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have 4 dataframes like as given below

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101, 101,101],
     'prod_id':[12,13,16],
     'total_qty':[100,1000,80],
     'ques_date' : ['13/11/2020', '10/1/2018','11/11/2017']})

df_accu = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101,101,101],
     'prod_id':[12,13,16],
     'accu_qty':[10,500,10],
     'accu_date' : ['13/08/2021','02/11/2019','17/12/2018']})

df_inv = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101,101,101],
     'prod_id':[12,13,18],
     'inv_qty':[5,100,15],
     'inv_date' : ['16/02/2022', '22/11/2020','19/10/2019']})

df_bkl = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_id' : [101,101,101,101],
     'prod_id' :[12,12,12,17],
     'bkl_qty' :[15,40,2,10],
     'bkl_date':['16/01/2022', '22/10/2021','09/10/2020','25/06/2020']})
```

My objective is to find out the below

a) Get the date when threshold exceeds 50%

threshold is given by the formula below

```
threshold = (((df_inv['inv_qty']+df_bkl['bkl_qty']+df_accu['accu_qty'])/df_raw['total_qty'])*100)
```

We have to add in the same order. Meaning, first, we have to add `inv_qty`, then `bkl_qty` and finally `accu_qty`.We do this way in order to identify the correct date when they exceeded 50% of total qty. Additionally, this has to be computed for each `stud_id` and `prod_id`.

but the problem is `df_bkl` has multiple records for the same `stud_id` and `prod_id` and it is by design. Real data also looks like this. Whereas `df_accu` and `df_inv` will have only row for each `stud_id` and `prod_id`.

In the above formula for df['bkl_qty'],`we have to use each value of df['bkl_qty']` to compute the sum.

for ex: let's take `stud_id = 101` and `prod_id = 12`.

His `total_qty = 100`, `inv_qty = 5`, his `accu_qty=10`. but he has three `bkl_qty` values - 15,40 and 2. So, threshold has to be computed in a fashion like below

5 (is value of inv_qty) +15 (is 1st value of bkl_qty) +40 (is 2nd value of bkl_qty) +2 (is 3rd value of bkl_qty) +10(is value of accu_qty)

So, now with the above, we can know that his threshold exceeded 50% when his `bkl_qty` value was 40. Meaning, 5+15+40 = 60 (which is greater than 50% of total_qty (100)).

I was trying something like below

```
df_stage_1 = df_raw.merge(df_inv,on=['stud_id','prod_id'], how='left').fillna(0)
df_stage_2 = df_stage_1.merge(df_bkl,on=['stud_id','prod_id'])
df_stage_3 = df_stage_2.merge(df_accu,on=['stud_id','prod_id'])
df_stage_3['threshold'] = ((df_stage_3['inv_qty'] + df_stage_3['bkl_qty'] + df_stage_3['accu_qty'])/df_stage_3['total_qty'])*100
```

But this is incorrect as I am not able to do each value by value for `bkl_qty` from `df_bkl`

In this post, I have shown only sample data with one `stud_id=101` but in real time I have more than 1000's of `stud_id` and `prod_id`.

Therfore, any elegant and efficient approach would be useful. We have to apply this logic on million record datasets.

I expect my output to be like as shown below. whenever the sum value exceeds 50% of total_qty, we need to get that corresponding date

```
stud_id,prod_id,total_qty,threshold,threshold_date
  101     12       100       72      22/10/2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using `groupby` and `cumsum` which does cumulative summation.

```
# add cumulative sum column to df_bkl
df_bkl['csum'] = df_bkl.groupby(['stud_id','prod_id'])['bkl_qty'].cumsum()

# use df_bkl['csum'] to compute threshold instead of bkl_qty
df_stage_3['threshold'] = ((df_stage_3['inv_qty'] + df_stage_3['csum'] + df_stage_3['accu_qty'])/df_stage_3['total_qty'])*100
# check if inv_qty already exceeds threshold
df_stage_3.loc[df_stage_3.inv_qty > df_stage_3.total_qty/2, 'bkl_date'] = df_stage_3['inv_date']

# next doing some filter and merge to arrive at the desired df
gt_thres = df_stage_3[df_stage_3['threshold'] > df_stage_3['total_qty']/2]
df_f1 = gt_thres.groupby(['stud_id','prod_id','total_qty'])['threshold'].min().to_frame(name='threshold').reset_index()
df_f2 = gt_thres.groupby(['stud_id','prod_id','total_qty'])['threshold'].max().to_frame(name='threshold_max').reset_index()

df = pd.merge(df_f1, df_stage_3, on=['stud_id','prod_id','total_qty','threshold'], how='inner')
df2 = pd.merge(df,df_f2, on=['stud_id','prod_id','total_qty'], how='inner')
df2 = df2[['stud_id','prod_id','total_qty','threshold','bkl_date']].rename(columns={'threshold_max':'threshold', 'bkl_date':'threshold_date'})
print(df2)
```

provides the output as:

```
   stud_id  prod_id  total_qty  threshold threshold_date
0      101       12        100       72.0     22/10/2021
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks, upvoted..will try and update you

Comment: But the threshold value in your output is incorrect

Comment: Do you want the minimum quantity at which the threshold became greater than 50% or you want to total threshold as a sum of bkl_qty?

Comment: I want to know when the threshold exceeded 50% of total_qty. So, we first check by adding inv_qty. Later, we add each value of bkl_qty one by one and finally we add accu_qty. From this summation process, i would like to know when did it exceed 50% of total_qty..

Comment: Updated code in the answer to take max threshold instead of the point where it exceeds 50% of total_qty

Comment: But I think your code checks when the `bkl_qty` exceeds 50%. But the logic is to check for each column. Fortunately, in this sample data, the exceed happens with bkl_qty(2nd value). For ex: Let's say this same stud_id and prod_id had inv_qty as 700 (instead of current value which is 5) which is greater than 50% of total_qty. So, we should get the `inv_date` as the date when it exceed 50% total_qty. Hope it helps. Or, am I interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: So if df_inv.inv_qty was 700, then the output should be: `101,12,100,767.0,16/02/2022`. Am I correct? If yes, then its just a simple adding of one more if condition

Comment: yes, correct. But the challenge is threshold can exceed 50% in any of the columns. It can exceed in `inv_qty` or `accu_qty` or `bkl_qty` as well. So, when we add one by one from inv_qty to bkl_qty to accu_qty, we need to keep track of that sum. But yes, your logic is helpful for me to guide on how to think.

Comment: Added one check for `inv_qty` in the code above. You will probably need one more at the end for `accu_qty` which can be implemented in the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242445/discussion-between-the-great-and-pankaj-saini).